# How to create Visual Studio 2017 multi template VSIX project?

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2017, prism

I'm trying to create an VSIX extension with Visual Studio 2017. My idea is that this extension can contain more than one template inside, It means that with one vsix installer, I want to install more than one template in Visual Studio (something like Prism Template pack).

I have the next scenario:

Two C# template project and one VSIX Project.

[image]

In the asset section of VSIX project, I'm referencing the output of my two template project:

[image]

But when I search them in Visual Studio for looking if they are installed, there is only one of them:
[image]

Both template project have same category, so it suppose they have to be in same folder.

Is there any configuration or something I'm missing to achieve the behavior I described?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did make it work. It was my mistake:

The template project were on different folder, but the output filename was the same, so, when the VSIX project  was compiled overwrite the file and only showed one of them.

My solution was giving one unique name for each template project and that's all.